# get unique visitors count with certain page ids - php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using wordpress. I've collected daily views (total and unique) and now want to see monthly statistics for certain pages. I could get total views but have an issue when getting unique views. I did the below:

```
$ids = '181,57,123';
$certainPageIds = explode(',', $ids);
foreach($certainPageIds as $id){
    $uniqueViews = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT distinct IP as all_uniques, 
    DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date, '%b' ) as month_name, DATE_FORMAT( insertion_date, 
    '%Y-%M' ) as full_date FROM daily_unique_views WHERE page_id = '".$id."'");
    if($uniqueViews){
        $uniqueViewsEncodedArray = json_decode(json_encode($uniqueViews), True);
        var_dump($uniqueViewsEncodedArray);
    }
}
```

And the above array returns the below:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["all_uniques"]=>
    string(13) "111.11.11.111"
    ["month_name"]=>
    string(3) "Dec"
    ["full_date"]=>
    string(13) "2016-December"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["all_uniques"]=>
    string(13) "22.222.222.22"
    ["month_name"]=>
    string(3) "Dec"
    ["full_date"]=>
    string(13) "2016-December"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["all_uniques"]=>
    string(13) "111.11.11.111"
    ["month_name"]=>
    string(3) "Nov"
    ["full_date"]=>
    string(13) "2016-November"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["all_uniques"]=>
    string(13) "111.11.11.111"
    ["month_name"]=>
    string(3) "Dec"
    ["full_date"]=>
    string(13) "2016-December"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["all_uniques"]=>
    string(12) "33.333.3.333"
    ["month_name"]=>
    string(3) "Dec"
    ["full_date"]=>
    string(13) "2016-December"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["all_uniques"]=>
    string(13) "111.11.11.111"
    ["month_name"]=>
    string(3) "Oct"
    ["full_date"]=>
    string(13) "2016-October"
  }
}
```

So it returns each page's monthly unique views. But how you notice, `111.11.11.111` appears many times. So I have same IP for december for each of the pages. But I need to have same IP counted for each month only once. How can I reach to this? Is there something to do with existing result or it should be fixed with sql? Any ideas please?

Comment: have you tried adding group by IP?

Comment: yes I tried but in that case I'm losing some ips. So when it sees that current IP already exists, it doesn't select it but for example, that was uniqur for another month so I lost that one unique view for that month @atoms

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cte (common table expresson), something like below:

```
DECLARE @ips TABLE(
    id int,
    ip varchar(3),
    month varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO @ips VALUES (1,'ip1', 'jan')
INSERT INTO @ips VALUES (2,'ip2', 'jan')
INSERT INTO @ips VALUES (3,'ip1', 'feb')
INSERT INTO @ips VALUES (4,'ip2', 'feb')
INSERT INTO @ips VALUES (5, 'ip2', 'jan');

-- Define the CTE expression name and column list.
WITH cte_ips (ip, month)
AS
-- Define the CTE query.
(
    SELECT ip, month FROM @ips
)
-- count the results
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip), COUNT(ip), month FROM Cte_ips GROUP BY Month



-- Define the outer query referencing the CTE name.
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP) AS UniqueIPs, COUNT(IP) AS TotalIPs, month FROM cte_ips
GROUP BY month
```

Comment: does MySQL support `CTE` and `WITH` clause? @atoms

Comment: No your correct, didn't realise this was for MySQL. You could move into a table var or temp table in the same was as the CTE query then query that?

Comment: is there any other solution you think about please? @atoms

Comment: Nested queries and set some vars? Think first solution would be better. Can update with an example? SQL not a strong point..

Comment: I don't imagine your first solution, that's why if you could give some example with mysql query then I can imagine @atoms

Comment: I guess I found a solution

Comment: would you still like me to provide one?

Comment: Thanks anyways but I guess no need. @atoms